# how url in plain context of html can be clickable

Tags: html

I did some self study of django and has question about url show as hyperlink:

This is the html part:

```
 <div class="rowalt2">
    <b>example:</b> <span class="right">{{ exmaple }}</span>
 </div>**
```

and example is something like "This is testing, please viste www.example.com".

I want the "www.example.com" become hyperlink instead of plain text.

Comment: <a href="www.example.com">www.example.com</a>

Comment: the examle is dynamic value returned by a function.

Comment: Show the 'function' from which it's returned; there's no reason (assuming the function is JavaScript or a sensible server-side language) that the function can't return a real `a` element instead of plain text. Otherwise, in 'plain html' (without [tag:javascript], [tag:php], etc) this can't be done.

Comment: @user2982128 If you are sure the url is safe:`<a href="http://{{example}}">{{example}}</a>`

Comment: the function is a python function read from a file and return a string "This is testing, please viste www.example.com"

Answer (score 0):

`<div class="rowalt2">
    <b>example:</b> <span class="right"><a href="http://www.example.com">{{example}}</a></span>
 </div>`

Replace the address in " " with the hyperlink. Don't remove the quotations.

Comment: the example is dynamic value not static. If it is a static value, i think you are right.